# Connection reset by peer while reading response header from upstream (NGINX)

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, phalcon

Im trying to run the local project (php phalcon) using nginx on macOS but it seems nginx can't load the project correctly.

**Here is my nginx log given :**

```
2023/01/12 11:38:04 [error] 6170#0: *1 kevent() reported about an closed connection (54: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: bahana.front, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9074", host: "127.0.0.1:7002"
2023/01/12 11:38:05 [error] 6170#0: *1 kevent() reported about an closed connection (54: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: bahana.front, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9074", host: "127.0.0.1:7002", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:7002/"
```

**and here is my site nginx config :** (for loading the php phalcon project)

```
server {
   listen 7002; 

   root /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bahana-front/bahana/public;
   index index.php;

   server_name  bahana.front;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9074;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }
 }
```

**also the php-fpm work well in the background (port 9074) :**

[image]

So, what did i miss for the configuration, im little stuck and keep getting closed connection at nginx log and HTTP Error 502 (Bad Gateway) when accessing the site at http://127.0.0.1:7002, Gonna need your help, thanks.

Comment: There are a few differences in your configuration file with the ones recommended for Phalcon, specially `fastcgi_pass`: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/webserver-setup#phalcon-configuration